# SSH copy ID failed

Tags: ssh, sshfs

Where should be an error? Local PC is Ubuntu.

command:

```
ssh-copy-id user@example.com
```

result:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
user@example.com's password: 
exec request failed on channel 0
```

Comment: If you're trying to add a public key where you don't need to enter password to login to that said remote location.. Well, I see you have not specified the key path in which should be copied. **E.g.:** `ssh-copy-id -i /home/user/passwordless_rsa.pub user@example.com`

Comment: yes, I am trying to add public key, but when I try it with `ssh-copy-id -i /home/user/passwordless_rsa.pub user@example.com` result and output is the same

Comment: Be cautious on what you're doing. Just to remind you about the security issues that can encounter. How have you created the ssh-key?? well you may have to give the proper path for the `.pub` key.. Also refer this [**SSH Tips & Tricks**](http://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2011/05/02/ssh-tips-and-tricks/) for more.

Comment: ssh key was created by `ssh-keygen -t rsa`

Answer (score 3):

> Note: This post is a clarification to OP's original answer to attempt to make it more clear (at least to me).

It appears that the server is running on SSH v2 instead of OpenSSH, which is the format that the SSH public key is in.

Because of this issue, the server is unable to actually handle reading and negotiating the public key in such a way that makes sense to everything. Essentially, this is like entering a password and having it be typed as English when the server was expecting it to be in Greek.

So, in order to fix this, we need to convert the OpenSSH key to a SSHv2 (otherwise known as RFC4716) key. OpenSSH provides a command to do this:

```
ssh-keygen -e -f /path/to/openssh/public/key > /path/you/want/the/rfc4716/key
```

Run this, and take the output and upload it to the server, if the keys haven't already been converted server-side.

Answer (score 0):

On server was changed SSH to SSH2. That was a reason. It was solved by converting the key.

Comment: This answer is very unclear for me. Could you please elaborate (a) what was changed and (b) how you converted the key?